# Saving number in array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to save scanned values in array. Sounds easy but here is where I'm having problems:
Here is the edited code reported as working from other members:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int length;       
   scanf("%d ", &length);
   int array[length];        // Added the missing ;

   for(int i=0; i<length; i++) // Loop from 0
   {
      scanf("%d ", &array[i]); // Used & properly here.
   }

   for(int j=0; j<length; j++)  // Loop from 0
   {
      printf("%d\n", array[j]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

What I'm having problems with now is that the program still needs 11 numbers to run. So if I enter

```
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Nothing happens until I enter another number.

EDIT: Finally figured out why it waits for 11th number: apparently it waits to get another whitespace so I just replaced scanf("%d ") with scanf(" %d) and it's working.

Comment: Indexing starts with `0` in C.

Comment: Also **length** is not initialized.

Comment: @ArifBurhan: `length` is obtained from the `scanf()` call. OP is using VLAs.

Comment: Both loops must start at `0`: `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)` and `for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)`

Comment: @pmg That prints out 9 numbers but for some reason needs 10 inputs instead of 9?

Comment: I'm surprised it worked at all, since you didn't pass `&array[i]` to `scanf()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/C arrays are 0-based index, If you have to access first element of the array you have to use 0 index not 1, consider this array of size 5 (i.e. five elements in it {23} {19} {6} {70} {9} )

- [0]->23
- [1]->19
- [2]->6
- [3]->70
- [4]->9

Please be-informed that the 0 position(index) of your array is not initialized. Now bearing this mind here's explanation of your code.

```
int main()
{
    int length = 0;     //Please consider initializing it
    scanf("%d ", &length); //User input '10'

    //Now you have an array of size 10 (10 consecutive memory locations to store int
    int array[length];    

    //Now consider the memory locations somewhat like this with raw values say 'xx'
    //0:[xx], 1:[xx], 2:[xx], 3:[xx], 4:[xx], 5:[xx], 6:[xx], 7:[xx], 8:[xx], 9:[xx]
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &array[i]); //Notice the fix here '&array[i] is used.
    }

    //After providing some data the memory view is somewhat like this, 
    //notice the loop started from position/index 1 in array and went
    //upto 9th position
    //0:[xx], 1:[11], 2:[22], 3:[33], 4:[44], 5:[55], 6:[66], 7:[77], 8:[88], 9:[99]

    for (int j = 1; j < length; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[j]);
    }

    //The above loop started from position 1 (not 0) and loop through 9 indexes and printed this
    //11
    //22
    //33
    //44
    //55
    //66
    //77
    //88
    //99

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the fixed code, notice the for loops starting from '0' based index.

```
int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    scanf("%d ", &length);
    int array[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &array[i]); //Notice the fix here '&array[i] is used.
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it would help you understand how arrays are handled in C++/C

Answer (score 2):

1. Arrays count from 0, not from one as we usually do ourselves. Therefore you should start your for loops at 0
2. You should be passing `&array[i]` to scanf in your first for loop.

Comment: Counting from 0 requires 10 inputs in the program instead of 9 then.

Comment: no - update the code with the two fixes and repost it

Comment: Because it will count from 0 to 9, so 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; which is 10 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

See inline comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int length;       
   scanf("%d ", &length);       // You used & properly here!
   int array[length]            // You forgot a semi-colon here!

   for(int i=1; i<length; i++)  // Loop: for(int i=0; i<length; ++i)
   {
      scanf("%d ", array[i]);   // Why didn't you use & here???
   }

   for(int j=1; j<length; j++)  // Loop: for(int j=0; j<length; ++j)
   {
      printf("%d\n", array[j]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here is an [***IDEOne link***](http://ideone.com/YAOlxc) to a program, that demonstrates it is working properly with `length=10` and 10 numbers as input

The fully corrected code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int length;       
   scanf("%d ", &length);
   int array[length];        // Added the missing ;

   for(int i=0; i<length; i++) // Loop from 0
   {
      scanf("%d ", &array[i]); // Used & properly here.
   }

   for(int j=0; j<length; j++)  // Loop from 0
   {
      printf("%d\n", array[j]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

***Input***

```
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Pasted the corrected code, compiled and ran it, the program still wants 11 numbers (if the length is entered as 10. I seriously don't know where am I going wrong?

Comment: You must show, in ***exact detail*** , what input you're giving your program.  It is not enough to say "the program wants".  We cannot see your program; we cannot see your input.  You must provide detail.

Comment: The input is 10(which is length) then entering 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 (if I try running it with 10 numbers nothing happens, just waits until another number is entered)

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current, correct code.   Repeated tests with my code demonstrate that it seems to be working in all cases.